# Biggest product from combination of positive numbers

Tags: calculus

From all combination of positive numbers,
Which have sum of 10, which one has the biggest product? And what's the product?

Tried to get an equation but failed.
I think it has to do with "e" or something.
Thanks.

Comment: "Tried to get an equation but failed." What did you try and why did it fail?

Comment: $y=x(10-x) $ but it doesn't make sense with the clue of $e$

Comment: I don't see why $e$ is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: $n+2\le 2\times n$, for all $n\ge 2$.

Therefore, any multiplicand $(n+2)\ge 4$ can be replaced by the two multiplicands $n,2$ to yield a larger product.  Hence we may assume that each multiplicand is strictly less than 4.

Hint #2: If $y\le 4$ and $x\le \frac43$, then $x+y\ge xy$.

Therefore, any multiplicand $x\le \frac43$ can be added to any other multiplicand thus raising the product.  Hence we may assume that each multiplicand is in $(\frac{4}{3},4)$.

Hint #3: If $x,y\ge 0$, then $2.5(2.5+x-y)\ge(2.5+x)(2.5-y)$.

Therefore, if there are multiplicands both less than and greater than $2.5$, then without loss we may replace them with $2.5$ and another multiplicand.  Hence we may assume that all multiplicands are either $\ge$ or $\le$ 2.5.

Comment: Thanks I know it should be bigger than $2$, like $2.5^4$ but can't see the connection to $e$ and how to prove it

Comment: If each multiplicand is in $(\frac{4}{3}, 4)$ how can they have sum $10$?

Comment: @Michael: The problem didn’t limit the number of multiplicands to $2$.

Comment: Usually this problem limits the numbers to integers; then you want as many 3's as possible, and just enough 2's to make the mod 3 work out correctly.  This is an interesting variation.

Comment: Can you show example for numbers that add up to $10$ end their product is bigger than $2.5^4$? And still didn't get what is the bigges product.